# Unable to setup crontab script

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, cron

I am trying to run a script from `crontab` but it keeps on telling me permissions denied even after I added a username.

I got the error message in `/var/mail/ubuntu`

first time I have this crontab setup like this. `crontab -e` shows:

```
* * * * * /home/ubuntu/abc/abc/dev_cron.sh
```

I would get the below as error message in `/var/mail/ubuntu`

```
/bin/sh: 1: /home/ubuntu/abc/abc/dev_cron.sh: Permission denied
```

then I changed the `crontab -e` to

```
* * * * * ubuntu /home/ubuntu/abc/abc/dev_cron.sh
```

as I have read some other posts saying where I typed `ubuntu` is the `username` but then I would still get such error message:

```
/bin/sh: 1: ubuntu: not found
```

then I should of changing `ubuntu` to `sudo` and I would get such error message:

```
sudo: /home/ubuntu/abc/abc/dev_cron.sh: command not found
```

I have used `ls -l` and saw that the file `dev_cron.sh` does belong to `ubuntu`.

Can someone please give me a hand what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script probably does not have execute permission. You can add it with:

```
chmod +x /home/ubuntu/abc/abc/dev_cron.sh
```

Comment: ah thx thx, I thought checking if the user name group are the same then I would already have the execute permission. Seems to be working but now getting another error for what I wrote in the script.  Thx thx